# How to check passed callback is called from tested method when using OCMock?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ocmock

How to check passed callback block is called from tested method? Here's simplified method I want to test:

```
- (void)loadModel:(Callback)callback {

  // Data loading part...

  // Callbacks with data. Second param usually passes data, but now it will pas nil for demo
  callback(YES, nil, nil);
}
```

Here's my unit test where I want to test if callback was called in method `loadModel`:

```
- (void)testLoadModelCallbackIsCalled {

  HomeModel *model = [[HomeModel alloc] init];
  id modelMock = OCMPartialMock(model);

  Callback callback = ^(BOOL success, id result, NSError *error){

    XCTAssertTrue(YES, @"Callback not called");
  };

  //[modelMock expect] ...how to expect?];

  [model loadModel:callback];

  //[modelMock verify];
}
```

The problem is this test will always pass regardless of callback was called on not. Thought to workaround this with proxy block, however then the whole `loadModel` method is overridden with the proxy block. I just need to verify `loadModel` actually calls what I pass.

**UPDATE** Meanwhile I ended in simplified workaround:

```
- (void)testLoadModelCallbackIsCalled {

  HomeModel *model = [[HomeModel alloc] init];

  // Create flag for checking
  __block BOOL isCalled = NO;

  Callback callback = ^(BOOL success, id result, NSError *error){

    isCalled = YES;
  };

  XCTAssertTrue(isCalled, @"Callback not called");
}
```

**UPDATE2** @jszumski answer was exactly what I was looking for thought the idea behind XCTestExpectation is very similar to using your own isCalled bool flag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `XCTestExpectation`, which is part of the asynchronous testing framework:

```
- (void)testLoadModelCallbackIsCalled {
    HomeModel *model = [[HomeModel alloc] init];
    id modelMock = OCMPartialMock(model);

    XCTestExpectation *expectation = [self expectationWithDescription:@"Completion called"];
    Callback callback = ^(BOOL success, id result, NSError *error){
        [expectation fulfill];
    };

    [model loadModel:callback];

    [self waitForExpectationsWithTimeout:1 handler:nil];
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I already started thinking this is the limitation of blocks.